# OnClick wrong item getting selected

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview with names and mobile numbers as the two textviews in it. OnItemClickListener returns a different item onclick. This is happening inconsistently- sometimes it selects the right item but sometimes it does not.

```
private void showCustomers(String json) {
        ParseCustomer parseCustomer = new ParseCustomer(json);
        parseCustomer.parseJSON();
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_customerInfo);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_customerinfo, R.id.customer_name,ParseCustomer.name);


        final List<Map<String, String>> cust = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String,String> map;
        int counter = ParseCustomer.name.length;
        for (int i=0;i<counter; i++){
            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name",ParseCustomer.name[i]);
            map.put("mobile",ParseCustomer.mobile_no[i]);
            cust.add(map);
        }

        newAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,cust,R.layout.list_customerinfo,new String[]{"name","mobile"},new int[]{R.id.customer_name,R.id.customer_mobile});
        lv.setAdapter(newAdapter);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                AddInvEst.this.newAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Map custSel = cust.get(position);
                custSelected = (String) custSel.get("name")+" "+ custSel.get("mobile");
                inputSearch.setText(custSelected);
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, "Your selected customer is "+custSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
}
```

I have an edit text field which I am using to search or filter the listview.
Can anyone just spot my mistake or guide me to a better solution? Thanks :)

Comment: Problem is with search filter, Try  `Map custSel = newAdapter.getItem(position);` instead of `Map custSel = cust.get(position);`

Comment: Post your adapter class

Comment: why `lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: @Amy I am using this list for search so when i don't need the list I am either making it invisible or gone

Comment: try to remove this from `onItemClick`

Comment: @user3295583 You are getting same result?

Comment: @DhavalPatel It worked  Map custSel = (Map) newAdapter.getItem(position);

Comment: @DhavalPatel can you tell me why it was selecting wrong items.

Comment: @user3295583 because  `newAdapter.getItem(position);` return `Object` so you need to cast it to Map. :-)

Comment: @user3295583 I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleAdapter` class manage two List, `One to store your original List` and `second to store filter data. So whenever you apply filter` on `SimpleAdapter` class, filter List has less number of item then the original one.

So in current scenario whenever you click on particular item, you getting click position of filtered List but you are getting item from unfiltered(original) List, Hence wrong item.

So to get click item from `SimpleAdapter` use:

```
Map custSel = (Map) newAdapter.getItem(position);
```